# Can DirectChannel be used in Spring Integration with Project Reactor without blocking?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, project-reactor

The [documentation of Spring Integration specifies that](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/channel.html#flux-message-channel) in the context of `FluxMessageChannel`:

> To achieve fully reactive behavior for the whole integration flow,
> such a channel must be placed between all the endpoints in the flow.

It makes me thinking whether it is also possible to use the `DirectChannel` when working with Reactive Streams, or can it cause any issues for the event loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends how blocking is a `MessageHandler` subscribed to that `DirectChannel`. Its purpose is to call a `MessageHandler` directly on a thread which has sent a message to this `DirectChannel`. So, if you do `.map(e -> directChannel.send(e))`, you need to be sure that `MessageHandler` is not blocking.